# IO Error while resizing a sorl ImageField in save() method - with s3boto

Tags: django, django-models, sorl-thumbnail, django-storage

I have the following:

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField, get_thumbnail

class MyMoldel(models.Model):   
    image = ImageField(uploat to = 'images')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.image:
            self.image = get_thumbnail(self.image, '320x180', quality=90, format='PNG')
        super(BaseReward, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I get the following error on uploading and image and trying to save in the admin panel:

```
OError at /admin/rewards/basereward/5/
File does not exist: Rewards Default.png
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/rewards/basereward/5/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
File does not exist: Rewards Default.png
Exception Location: /Users/xyz/voltbe2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py in _open, line 366
```

The error comes (I have checked by omitting lines of code) from get_thumbnail trying to open self.image. How do I convert this into a s3boto path to pass on to get_thumbnail?

thanks

Comment: Have you solved this problem?